# Blazor: Get `ActionContext`

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm converting the scaffolded ASP.Net Identity pages from Razor Pages to Blazor. I've hit a snag and hope you can help. `ChallengeResult.ExecuteResultAsync` requires an instance of `ActionContext`. Is there an instance of this in a Server-Side Blazor App and how can I get to it?

### EDIT

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'ActionContextAccessor' on type 'OCR.UI.Site.Pages.Account.ExternalLogin'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.IActionContextAccessor'.

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory+<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateInitializer>g__Initialize|2(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IComponent component)
```

No joy.

Comment: There's an [`IActionContextAccessor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.infrastructure.iactioncontextaccessor?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that you can inject similar to `IHttpContextAccessor` but I do not know if it applies to Blazor

Comment: Have you looked at how Blazor does auth views?

Comment: Yes, I am working with the Razor Pages templates generated from the official nuget package.  There are several Blazorisms that require doing things differently such as not doing a postback but calling a method instead.

Answer (score 2):

`ActionContext`, as its name also implies, relates to MVC, specifically "actions", which are the methods that you can call on controllers by correctly addressing their HTTP endpoints.

In an MVC app, you can get the current `ActionContext` if you register an `IActionContextAccessor` object to the DI container and try to access its value. The `ActionContext` describes which controller's which action was hit, and what parameters are bound via routing and model binding.

In MVC, you won't *always* have an `ActionContext`, however. In the MVC app's process, you might have other code that does not necessarily get triggered by an MVC controller's action. This might be some background processes you run to send emails, a SignalR hub to communicate realtime with clients, gRPC or just another thread that runs in the app not doing the job of processing the incoming HTTP request. You might even be in the HTTP pipeline, but not MVC! If you have a middleware serving HTTP responses, you won't have an `ActionContext`. Thus, the accessor pattern. If you don't have an `ActionContext`, the value will be null.

In Blazor Server, you only have an HTTP request during the initial rendering of the page, or when you are doing `static` rendering (essentially when you use `<component render-mode="Static">`, which renders a non-interactive Blazor component, essentially as a string into the HTML output). For this reason, it is **never advised** to use the `ActionContext`, even if one is available via the accessor, in Blazor Server. When the user types in the full URL of your page, you will have an `ActionContext`. But once the user navigates **in-app** to that same page, there is no `HTTP` communication whatsoever stemming from that navigation.

In short, in Blazor Server, don't use `ActionContext` even if you can access one, because it is bad design and it won't work when navigating to that page from another Blazor component.

For your specific problem, you have to go and call different lower-level APIs of the Identity framework (like to check a user's password), and not rely on HTTP. In Blazor Server, your code **already** runs on the server, in real time connection with the client, responding to the client's interactions. You can't "put down cookies" for instance in the same way you could in MVC, because there is no HTTP response to send the `Set-Cookie` header in. Thus, you need a server-side rendered solution that does full-postback and a server that handles the incoming requests. That's essentially Razor Pages (or MVC). Because of this, there is no straightforward or out-of-the-box way to simply migrate the Identity scaffolded pages "page-by-page". The interactions have to be repurposed so that they are compatible with Blazor Server, or in the rare cases they are not (which usually come down to needing to set or read server-readable cookies), you might use the aforementioned `static` rendering mode in Blazor, Razor Pages, or additional client-side logic (like JavaScript) that handles the posting of a form or a full-postback navigation to a URL.